# Designing clock ticks

Tags: inkscape

With InkScape, it's rather easy by using "Path Effects" of "Rotate copies":

[image]

Result:

[image]

Now, I wish some of these ticks to be thicker **and** shorter (at mins 5, 10, 15...).

So, I can obviously create a new path and apply the same "Rotate copies" with only 12 copies:

[image]

As these new ones are shorter, I will also have to remove these ones from the 60 copies (as this shorter & thicker ticks won't look good when placed on top of the 60s anyway):

[image]

So what I could do is to do path to object/stroke to path conversion, and remove the unneeded ones by hand:

[image]

Now it looks as I want, however I lost the ability to **change** the 60 (now only 60-12=48) small ticks' size (width/height), as those are now pure paths.

Can I somehow use "Rotate copies" to regularly skip items around the circumference to keep my objects/strokes ?

Comment: Not really, even if you could describing exceptions would be more work than just deleting the duplicates. But i guess you could make first 5 lines modify one and rotate the group of 5 the rest of the way. Not sure its less work

Comment: Awesome idea! Created 4 copies, then with another "Rotate copies" 12 of these 4s. Perfect. Thank you

Comment: It may be worthwhile adding that solution as a full answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable the 'Split elements' option in the parameters of the 'Rotate copies' path-effect, to make all the copies separate objects, that you can select and style independently:

[image: Screenshot from the question of the 'Rotate copies' parameters with the 'Split elements' option highlighted]

Now you can select the lines you want to style differently and set their stroke-width for example. If you need to select them again later, you can right-click one and use 'Select Same → Stroke Style'.

As for the line length, while you can't change the path-data of the copies, you can make them *visually* shorter by adding a dash style with a really long gap. In the 'Fill and Stroke' panel under the 'Stroke style' tab, change the 'Dashes' drop-down to 'Custom', which should make a 'Pattern' input appear. There you can enter a length in px, then an arbitrary large number for the gap. You can also play around with the offset input next to the drop-down to make the stroke start further along the path.

[image: Screenshot of an example result with the 'Path Effect' and 'Fill and Stroke' panels visible, showing the settings being used]